# AngularJS - JSON parse html

Tags: json, angularjs, html-parsing

I'm in a bit of a jam, I am getting data from an endpoint with angular, JSON, and sometimes that data could be HTML code, I read about it and I found out that if I want to parse that info as HTML, without `""`, I have to use `JSON.parse()`.

The problem is that now the code is escaped and throws an error before calling it in my template. http://screencast.com/t/zledZ6rBod

I can see why this is happening, but how can I output interpretable HTML markup in my template?

Comment: I tried to use `$sce.parseAs($sce.HTML, myJSONResponse.HTMLcontent)`   Another error. http://screencast.com/t/fdoiIEveMJ

Comment: Also tried with trustAsHtml: `$scope.projContent = $sce.trustAsHtml(data[i].posts[0].content);`

Comment: please post your client side code

Comment: I forgot to close this question :), it's from last year :). I'll post the answer in a jiffy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is using $sce, Strict Contextual Escaping, here are the docs:
 http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#methods_trustashtml

for me it worked doing it like this:

In the controller:

`$scope.theHtml = '<div class="red">Content</div>';
            $scope.parseHtml = function() {
                return $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.theHtml);
            };`

In the template:

`<div ng-bind-html="parseHtml()"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a simpler way to 'sanitize' an HTML string.

1. Import `angular-sanitize.min.js` into your HTML.
2. Add it as a dependency `var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize']);`
3. Then use `ng-bind-html="HTML_STRING_VAR_HERE"`

This way you don't have to make a function to sanitize and you can pass the variable directly.

You can see an example in this plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/4FBUSooNMpqk1rYAZYdZ
Let me know what you think.